# tabularray: align tabular with text

Tags: tabularray

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
Test 1
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, colspec={c}}
    Test 2 \\
    Test 3 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to align Test 1 and Test 2 (same baseline)?

Comment: You can use `\firsthline` and `\lasthline` with `tabularray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) version 2022A (2022-03-01), `\firsthline` and `\lasthline` commands are deprecated in favor of `baseline=T` and `baseline=B` specifications. You can write `baseline` option as either an inner specification or an outer specification. And when `baseline=T/B` is an outer specification, you can omit the key name and write the value only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\section{Tabularray}

Test 1
\begin{tblr}[T]{vlines, colspec={c}}
\hline
  Test 2 \\
\hline
  Test 3 \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
Test 1
\begin{tblr}[B]{vlines, colspec={c}}
\hline
  Test 2 \\
\hline
  Test 3 \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\section{Tabular}

Test 1
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|}
\firsthline
  Test 2 \\
\hline
  Test 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
Test 1
\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|}
\hline
  Test 2 \\
\hline
  Test 3 \\
\lasthline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

But you can still roll back to version 2021Q with `\usepackage{tabularray}[=v2021]`, so that you can use `\firsthline` and `\lasthline` commands in `tblr` environment. The usage is the same as in `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}[=v2021]
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\section{Tabularray}

Test 1
\begin{tblr}[t]{vlines, colspec={c}}
\firsthline
  Test 2 \\
\hline
  Test 3 \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
Test 1
\begin{tblr}[b]{vlines, colspec={c}}
\hline
  Test 2 \\
\hline
  Test 3 \\
\lasthline
\end{tblr}

\section{Tabular}

Test 1
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|}
\firsthline
  Test 2 \\
\hline
  Test 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
Test 1
\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|}
\hline
  Test 2 \\
\hline
  Test 3 \\
\lasthline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Test 2 in tabularray is 0.4pt below baseline and Test 3 0.4pt above baseline. I hope that in a newer version it gets fixed.

Comment: @polyn Thanks for your reporting. I will look into this problem later.

Comment: `\firsthline` and `\lasthline` were deprecated in favor of `baseline=T` and `baseline=B`

Comment: @JayLee Thanks. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

May I also suggest trying the `NiceTabular` environment from the `nicematrix` package. It lets you specify which line in the table you want to use as baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

Test 1
\begin{NiceTabular}{c}[baseline=1,hlines,vlines]
    Test 2 \\
    Test 3
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a good feature. I think `tabularray` should add it too some day .

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to include Test 1 in the table, but without borders around it. You could achieve that using `cline` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{Q[c,m]|Q[c,m]|}
    \cline{2-2}
    Test 1 & Test 2 \\
    \cline{2-2}
    & Test 3 \\
    \cline{2-2}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `tabularray`, you can write `\cline{2}` instead of `\cline{2-2}`.

Comment: @Zork thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very easy for me to understand this package but you can create every `vline` and `hline` yourself with considering the position of the elements of the array. I have thought to this, in function **only** for your image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
 hline{1,3} = {2-3}{solid},
 hline{2,3} = {2-3}{solid},
 vline{2,2} = {1-3}{solid},
 vline{3,3} = {1-3}{solid},
 vline{2,3} = {2-3}{solid},
}
 Test 1 & Test 1 \\
           & Test 2 
 \end{tblr}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**: On suggestion of the author of the package @L.J.R. here an improved with the same output (see the comment below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
 hlines = {2}{solid}, 
 vline{2-3} = {solid},
}
 Test 1 & Test 1 \\
           & Test 2 
 \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is enough with `hlines = {2}{solid}, vline{2-3} = {solid}`.

Comment: @Sebastiano thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @polyn I'm not expert on this field with this package but I'am very happy to help you.